# constant bluetooth pairing

Tags: java, android, button, bluetooth

Is there any code that could maintain connection between 2 devices without checking the pairing device repeatedly after click a button to run a program ? I assume that whenever i push a button, it will searching for pairing device, and when i release the button, it will disconnect the device. If this happens because of my code, please kindly tell me

Im open for any advices
thank you

```
public static enum CONN_TYPE {
    LEJOS_PACKET, LEGO_LCP
}
class UIMessageHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        switch (msg.what) {
            case MESSAGE:
                _message.setText((String) msg.getData().get(MESSAGE_CONTENT));

                break;

            case TOAST:
                showToast((String) msg.getData().get(MESSAGE_CONTENT));
                break;
        }

        _message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        _message.requestLayout();

    }

}
public static final String MESSAGE_CONTENT = "String_message";
public static final int MESSAGE = 1000;
public static final int TOAST = 2000;
//private BTSend Right;
private Right right;
private Backward backward;
private TachoCount tachoCount;
private Stop stop;
private Toast reusableToast;
private Left left;

private TextView _message;

//static final String START_MESSAGE = "Please make sure you NXT is on and both it and your Android handset have bluetooth enabled";
private static final String GO_AHEAD = "Choose one!";

public static UIMessageHandler mUIMessageHandler;

private final static String TAG = "LeJOSDroid";

public static NXTConnector connect(final CONN_TYPE connection_type) {
    Log.d(TAG, " about to add LEJOS listener ");

    NXTConnector conn = new NXTConnector();
    conn.setDebug(true);
    conn.addLogListener(new NXTCommLogListener() {

        public void logEvent(String arg0) {
            Log.e(TAG + " NXJ log:", arg0);
        }

        public void logEvent(Throwable arg0) {
            Log.e(TAG + " NXJ log:", arg0.getMessage(), arg0);
        }
    });

    switch (connection_type) {
        case LEGO_LCP:
            conn.connectTo("btspp://NXT", NXTComm.LCP);
            break;
        case LEJOS_PACKET:
            conn.connectTo("btspp://");
            break;
    }

    return conn;

}

public static void displayToastOnUIThread(String message) {
    Message message_holder = formMessage(message);
    message_holder.what = LeJOSDroid.TOAST;
    mUIMessageHandler.sendMessage(message_holder);
}

private static Message formMessage(String message) {
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString(LeJOSDroid.MESSAGE_CONTENT, message);
    Message message_holder = new Message();
    message_holder.setData(b);
    return message_holder;
}

public static void sendMessageToUIThread(String message) {
    Message message_holder = formMessage(message);
    message_holder.what = LeJOSDroid.MESSAGE;
    mUIMessageHandler.sendMessage(message_holder);
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mUIMessageHandler = new UIMessageHandler();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    _message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
    seupNXJCache();
    setupTachoCount(this);
    setupRight(this);
    setupBackward(this);
    setupLeft(this);
    reusableToast = Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}

/*@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (Right != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() closing btSend ");
        Right.closeConnection();
        Right = null;
    }

    if (tachoCount != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() closing btSend ");
        tachoCount.closeConnection();
    }
}*/

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

private void setupRight(final LeJOSDroid mActivity) {       

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {//button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent motion) {
            Toast.makeText(LeJOSDroid.this, "Button Clicked 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            do{
            try {
                right = new Right();
                right.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to run BTSend:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            } while (motion.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);

            return false;
        }

    });
}


private void setupBackward(final LeJOSDroid mActivity) {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent motion) {
            Toast.makeText(LeJOSDroid.this, "Button Clicked 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            do{
            try {
                backward = new Backward();
                //_message.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                backward.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to run TachoCount:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            } while (motion.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            return false;
        }
    } );
}

private void setupLeft(final LeJOSDroid mActivity) {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent motion) {
            Toast.makeText(LeJOSDroid.this, "Button Clicked 4", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            do{
            try {
                left = new Left();
                //_message.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                left.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to run TachoCount:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            } while (motion.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
            return false;
        }
    } );
}

private void setupTachoCount(final LeJOSDroid mActivity) {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent motion) {
            Toast.makeText(LeJOSDroid.this, "Button Clicked 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            do {
            try {
                tachoCount = new TachoCount();
                _message.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tachoCount.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to run TachoCount:" + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            }while (motion.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
        return false;
        }

    });
}

private void seupNXJCache() {

    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    try {
        String androidCacheFile = "nxj.cache";
        File mLeJOS_dir = new File(root + "/leJOS");
        if (!mLeJOS_dir.exists()) {
            mLeJOS_dir.mkdir();

        }
        File mCacheFile = new File(root + "/leJOS/", androidCacheFile);

        if (root.canWrite() && !mCacheFile.exists()) {
            FileWriter gpxwriter = new FileWriter(mCacheFile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(gpxwriter);
            out.write("");
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            _message.setText("nxj.cache (record of connection addresses) written to: " + mCacheFile.getName() + GO_AHEAD);
        } else {
            _message.setText("nxj.cache file not written as"
                    + (!root.canWrite() ? mCacheFile.getName() + " can't be written to sdcard." : " cache already exists.") + GO_AHEAD);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not write nxj.cache " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    _message.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    _message.requestLayout();
}

private void showToast(String textToShow) {
    reusableToast.setText(textToShow);
    reusableToast.show();
}
```

}